# Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1

Tags: python

I'm making a zip file with Python, but the process is interrupted.
dev/sdb1 is already mounted but this error:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1: Command-line `mount "/home/pi/hrc2"' exited with non-zero exit status 18: Failed to write lock '/dev/sdb1': Resource temporarily unavailable
Error opening '/dev/sdb1': Resource temporarily unavailable
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Python Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dosyaUploader.py", line 162, in <module>
    zd.write(rarlanacakdKlasor+"/"+sadecedosya,arcname=sadecedosya)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1493, in write
    buf = fp.read(1024 * 8)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Comment: what filesystem is on /dev/sdb1 ... you say it's already mounted, are you trying to mount it again?

Comment: File system is NTFS. 
Automatically re-mounting after failure.

Comment: if you search for that error, you'll see it's very common with NTFS on pi (and linux in general) - see if any of those search results help